# ruby - Array group_by sub elements

Tags: ruby

I need to group this YAML strutcture by array elements.

This is example of my YAML structure:

```
articles:
  - title: 'Title 1'
    url: 'https://example.com'
    data: July 21, 2017
    categories:
      - 'category 1'
      - 'category 2'
  - title: 'Title 2'
    url: 'https://example.com'
    data: July 23, 2017
    categories:
      - 'category 2'
```

Result I need is this or similar:

```
['category 1' => 
    [
        {title: 'Title 1', url: 'https://example.com', data: July 21, 2017, categories: ['category 1', 'category 2']}
    ], 
    'category 2' => [
        {title: 'Title 1', url: 'https://example.com', data: July 21, 2017, categories: ['category 1', 'category 2']},
        {title: 'Title 2', url: 'https://example.com', data: July 23, 2017, categories: ['category 2']}
    ]
]
```

Can you help me? Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

I have tried this:

```
articles.group_by(&:categories).map{|v, a| [v, a] }
```

but key is not single category, but categories elements. I think I need a more loop but after some trials I haven't get the result.

Sorry for this, but I newbie for ruby

**UPDATE 2:**
Wrong result is:

```
[
  [
    [
      "category 1",
      "category 2"
    ],
    [
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "data": "July 21, 2017",
        "categories": [
          "category 1",
          "category 2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "category 2"
    ],
    [
      {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "data": "July 23, 2017",
        "categories": [
          "category 2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated my question. Thank you

Comment: is the desired output correct? should category 2 be a subelement of category 1 ?

Comment: _"but key is not single category"_ – could you show the (wrong) result, please?

Comment: BTW, your expected result seems to be a hash, but is expressed as an array literal, i.e. you are using `[key => value]` instead of `{ key => value }`. Please fix that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: it's not a subelement. It is just misleadingly indented as such.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, in this case, the plain old good reducer would suit your needs better:

```
articles.each_with_object({}) do |article, acc|
  acc.merge! article.categories.map { |c| [c, article] }.to_h
end
```

or even:

```
articles.map do |article|
  article.categories.map { |c| [c, article] }.to_h
end.reduce(&:merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a group_by? Why not an easy nested loop?

```
result = {}
articels.each do |article|
  article.categories.each do |cat|
    result[cat] ||= []
    result[cat] << article
  end
end
```

Comment: You are abusing `each` with preliminary local variable. Please use `each_with_object` instead.

Comment: @mudasobwa that's true, it was more a statement, that he should have be able to solve this with easy methods. It was not the idea to show the best way. Anyway your solution is quite good, always glad to read something like this ;-)